# Google Cloud Platform design for a stateful application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stateful

Usecase:  Our requirement is to run a service continuously every few minutes. This service reads a value from datastore, and  hits a public url using that value from datastore (Stateful). This service doesnt have Front End. No body would be accessing this service publicly.   A new value is stored in datastore as a result of response from the url. Exactly one server is required to run.

We are in need to decide one of the below for our use case.

1. Compute Engine (IaaS -> we dont want to maintain the infra for this simple stateful application)
2. Kubernetes Engine (still feeling overkill )
3. App Engine : PaaS-> App Engine is usually used for Mobile apps, Gaming, Websites.  App Engine provides a url with web address. Is it right choice for our usecase? If we choose app engine, is it possible to stop the public app engine url?  Also, as one instance would be running continuously in app engine, what is cost effective - standard or flexible?
4. Cloud Functions -> Event Driven(looks not suitable for our application)
5. Google Cloud Scheduler-> We thought we could use cloud scheduler + cloud functions. But during outage, jobs are queued up. In our case, after outage, only one server/instance/job could be up and running.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your selection criteria (price, complexity, fault tolerance)? Any of the services listed will work in most cases. It is up to you to decide what meets your objectives which are not clearly defined in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> after outage, only one server/instance/job could be up and running

Limiting Cloud Function concurrency is enough? If so, you can do this:

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME --max-instances 1 FLAGS...
```

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances

I also recommend taking a look at Google Cloud Run, is a serverless docker platform, it can be limited to a maximum of 1 instances responding to a maximum of 1 request concurrently. It would require Cloud Scheduler too, making regular HTTP requests to it.

With both services configured with max concurrency of 1, only one server/instance/job will be up and running, but, after outages, jobs may be scheduled as soon as another finish. If this is problematic, adding a lastRun datetime field on datastore job row and not running if it's too recent, or disable retry of cloud scheduler, like said here:

[Google Cloud Tasks HTTP trigger - how to disable retry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117520/google-cloud-tasks-http-trigger-how-to-disable-retry)